# Unit Test for delete method in Java?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, junit5

I am trying to test the following method by a Unit Test:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void delete(UUID uuid) {
    final Company company = companyRepository.findByUuid(uuid)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException(COMPANY_NAME));

    deletionService.delete(company);
    companyRepository.save(company);
}
```

Here is the DeletionService implementation:

```
@Override
public void delete(final DeletableEntity deletableEntity) {
    deletableEntity.setDeleted(true);
    deletableEntity.setDeleteDate(Instant.ofEpochMilli(clock.millis()));
    deletableEntity.setDeletedByUserUuid(currentUser.getUuid());
}
```

I created the following test method:

```
@Test(expected = EntityNotFoundException.class)
public void test_Delete() {
    final UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
    final String name = "Company";
    final Company company = new Company(name);

    when(companyRepository.findByUuid(uuid)).thenReturn(Optional.of(company));

    companyService.delete(uuid);

    // I think this returns company instead of EntityNotFoundException 
    // due to the condition in "Mockito.when(...)"
    companyRepository.findByUuid(uuid);
}
```

The debugger hits until `companyRepository.findByUuid(uuid);` line without any problem, but executing this line does not throw error. I think this is due to the condition in "Mockito.when(...)". So, how should I modify this test so that I test my ***soft delete*** method?

Here is my `Company` entity that extends from `DeletableEntity`:

```
//some annotation here
public class Company extends DeletableEntity  {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "company_gen")
    private long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    public Company(@Nonnull String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return super.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        return super.equals(other);
    }
}
```

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class DeletableEntity extends BaseEntity {

    private boolean deleted;

    private Instant deleteDate;

    private UUID deletedByUserUuid;
}
```

***Update:*** Here is the last status of my edited methods:

```
@Test
public void test_Successful_Delete() {
    // Arrange
    final String name = "Company";
    final Company company = new Company(name);

    when(companyRepository.findByUuid(company.getUuid()))
        .thenReturn(Optional.of(company));
    doNothing().when(deletionService).delete(isA(Company.class));
    when(companyRepository.save(isA(Company.class))).thenReturn(company);

    // Act
    companyService.delete(company.getUuid());

    // Assert
    verify(deletionService, times(1)).delete(isA(Company.class));
    verify(companyRepository, times(1)).save(isA(Company.class));
}
```

```
@Test(expected = EntityNotFoundException.class)
public void test_Delete_thenThrowException() {
    final String name = "Company";
    final Company company = new Company(name);

    when(companyRepository.findByUuid(company.getUuid())).thenReturn(Optional.empty());

    companyService.delete(company.getUuid());
}
```

Comment: You aren't testing anything but the mocking framework. No query of sorts is executed because you are mocking the repository.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for reply. What is the solution? Which parts should I change?

Comment: What is it that you want to test? That the service does the right thing? Or something else? There is no database so there will be nothing database related in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to test such a method you have to do it with two tests:

1. Test that `companyRepository.save()` is indeed called if `companyRepository.findByUuid()` returns anything;
2. Test that the method throw `EntityNotFoundException` when `companyRepository.findByUuid()` returns nothing.

The 1. would be something like the following:

```java
@Test
public void test_Successful_Delete() {
    // Arrange
    final UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
    final String name = "Company";
    final Company company = new Company(name);
    when(companyRepository.findByUuid(uuid)).thenReturn(Optional.of(company));
    when(deletionService.delete(isA(Company.class))).thenReturn(true; // I am assuming deletionService.delete() returns a boolean, if that is not the case you will need to adjust this
    when(companyRepository.save(isA(Company.class))).thenReturn(true; // I am assuming companyRepository.save() returns a boolean, if that is not the case you will need to adjust this

    // Act
    companyService.delete(uuid);

    // Assert
    verify(deletionService, times(1)).delete(isA(Company.class));
    verify(companyRepository, times(1)).save(isA(Company.class));
}
```

The 2. would look as follows (similar to yours):

```java
@Test
public void test_Unsuccessful_Delete() {
    // Arrange
    final UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
    final String name = "Company";
    final Company company = new Company(name);
    when(companyRepository.findByUuid(uuid)).thenReturn(Optional.empty());

    try {
      // Act
      companyService.delete(uuid);
      Assert.fail("Exception not thrown");
    } catch (EntityNotFoundException e) {
      // Assert
      verify(deletionService, never()).delete(isA(Company.class));
      verify(companyRepository, never()).save(isA(Company.class));
    }
}
```

P.S.: `assertThat` is an AssertJ method (`org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat`).

Comment: **1.** What is `Mockito.verify(companyRepository, Mockito.times(1)).save(companyCaptor.capture());` line, how should I translate it?

Comment: **2.** `assertThat(companyCaptor.getValue().getDeleted()).isTrue();` retruns false. I traced code and even after `companyRepository.save()` line, `company.isDeleted()` is still false.

Comment: 1. It verifies that `companyRepository.save()` method was called only once (hence the `Mockito.times(1)`). The `capture()` part is just t get the object that was used in that call so that you can assert that `deleted` was actually set to `true`.

Comment: 2. That is weird because you have `company.deleted = true;` in your `delete(UUID uuid)` method. Can you please add `Company` class to your question? Thanks.

Comment: Can you please add `Company` itself and not only the superclass? The reason is that `boolean deleted` is private, which means that `company.deleted = true;` shouldn't even be possible. This makes me suspect that your `Company` class has some magic to allow this, or your code wouldn't even compile.

Comment: I added. Yes you are right, it is weird, but I set company's deleted property true by calling another service before `companyRepository.save(company);`

Comment: Wait, then the code in `delete(UUID uuid)` that is not your actual code? Please update it so that it reflects your exact code, otherwise, we can't really help your because we are seeing things differently than they are in reality. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but at first I added these codes, but then to make something clear for helpers, I omitted some of them. Now I added, sorry again.

Comment: I've updated my answer, please check it. Given that the deletion is delegated to some other Service then it does not make sense to check the `delete` property because it depends on `DeleteService` which is not the unit under test in this case.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have just found time to try your last updates. For the first method, I have some trouble with `isA` lines. What does it do exactly in here? And can we use another things instead of it?

Comment: It matches the argument if it implements the given class (https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.7.2/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html#isA(java.lang.Class)). You can always use `any()`, that basically matches anything, including nulls and varargs.

Comment: By the way, I add the edited version of the first method as Update in my question. As the delete method is void, I used `doNothing()`. The method is working, but I am not sure if all the lines are ok and if there is no problem regarding to update of the first method?

Comment: **1.** I added the edited versions of the method you suggested in the Update part of the question. As the delete method is void, I used `doNothing()`.

Comment: **2.** The methods are working, but I am not sure if all the lines are ok and if there is no problem regarding to these 2 methods. Could you check and inform me pls? ?

Comment: **3.** I still not understand the `verify()` method e.g. `verify(companyRepository, times(1)).save(isA(Company.class));`. Because we already call that save method 1 time and does it mean that we just checking that we call that method?

Comment: Your `test_Successful_Delete` test seems ok to me. And the `doNothing()` is also ok, I was simply not aware of what the return type of the call was.

Comment: 2. I would change your `test_Delete_thenThrowException` test to my suggestion so that you not only test that the exception is thrown but you also assert that `deletionService.delete()` and `companyRepository.save()` are not called as you expect.

Comment: 3. In that case, `verify()` checks that `companyRepository.save()` is called a single time with a `Company` object as a parameter. On the other hand `verify(companyRepository, never()).save(isA(Company.class));`, verifies that `companyRepository.save()` is never called.

Comment: Just an important issue: You check the next line is called after exception via `verify(deletionService, never()).delete(isA(Company.class));` and the next line. I am just wondering if we really need to verify using next line: `verify(companyRepository, never()).save(isA(Company.class));`. Because verifying the previous line meaning that the next line will not be executed. Is that true? Or should we verify all the lines after execution occured?

Comment: Yes, that would be true because that is the order of your code. But if you swap the methods then it might happen that it is no longer true. Having said that, it is always good to verify all relevant method calls.

Comment: Then I will verify all of the remaining calls, thanks a lot Amigo ;)

Comment: Voted up up up ... ;)